# Django Bootstrap module in ubuntu

Tags: django, apache

So deploying my django app into an unbuntu 20.04 with apache. I've got everything worked out(mostly). The latest kink is bootstrap. Now when I run the app through the built in django web server, it works beautifully. But when I try through apache, it gives an error that it can't find bootstrap:

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dAbbH.png)

I've verified the syntax is right in my HTML files as that is the most common issue via google. I thought maybe apache needed to have jquery installed, which I did sudo apt-get install libjs-jquery to get installed but that did not resolve the issue. So any help would be appreciated.

Environment:

```
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://tolleyfarminc.com/calves/

Django Version: 3.0.13
Python Version: 3.8.5
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'calves',
 'bootstrap4',
 'medical',
 'reports',
 'dairies',
 'accounts',
 'report_builder']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']


Template error:
In template /opt/TolleyFarms/templates/base_generic.html, error at line 8
   'bootstrap4' is not a registered tag library. Must be one of:
admin_list
admin_modify
admin_urls
cache
i18n
l10n
log
static
tz
   1 : <!DOCTYPE html>
   2 : <html lang="en">
   3 : <head>
   4 :     <meta charset="UTF-8">
   5 :     <title>base_generic</title>
   6 : 
   7 :     {% load static %}
   8 :      {% load bootstrap4 %} 
   9 :     {% bootstrap_css %}
   10 :     {% bootstrap_javascript jquery='full' %}
   11 : 
   12 : 
   13 : 
   14 : 
   15 : 
   16 : </head>
   17 : <body>
   18 :     <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark navbar-dark">


    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/opt/TolleyFarms/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 1021, in find_library
        return parser.libraries[name]
    
    During handling of the above exception ('bootstrap4'), another exception occurred:
      File "/opt/TolleyFarms/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
        response = get_response(request)
      File "/opt/TolleyFarms/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
        response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
      File "/opt/TolleyFarms/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
        response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
      File "/opt/TolleyFarms/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py", line 21, in _wrapped_view
        return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
      File "/opt/TolleyFarms/calves/views.py", line 21, in index
        return render(request, 'base_generic.html')
      File "/opt/TolleyFarms/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/shortcuts.py", line 19, in render
        content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)
      File "/opt/TolleyFarms/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 61, in render_to_string
        template = get_template(template_name, using=using)
      File "/opt/TolleyFarms/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 15, in get_template
        return engine.get_template(template_name)
      File "/opt/TolleyFarms/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 34, in get_template
        return Template(self.engine.get_template(template_name), self)
      File "/opt/TolleyFarms/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/engine.py", line 143, in get_template
        template, origin = self.find_template(template_name)
      File "/opt/TolleyFarms/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/engine.py", line 125, in find_template
        template = loader.get_template(name, skip=skip)
      File "/opt/TolleyFarms/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/loaders/base.py", line 29, in get_template
        return Template(
      File "/opt/TolleyFarms/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 156, in __init__
        self.nodelist = self.compile_nodelist()
      File "/opt/TolleyFarms/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 194, in compile_nodelist
        return parser.parse()
      File "/opt/TolleyFarms/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 477, in parse
        raise self.error(token, e)
      File "/opt/TolleyFarms/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 475, in parse
        compiled_result = compile_func(self, token)
      File "/opt/TolleyFarms/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 1078, in load
        lib = find_library(parser, name)
      File "/opt/TolleyFarms/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 1023, in find_library
        raise TemplateSyntaxError(

Exception Type: TemplateSyntaxError at /calves/
Exception Value: 'bootstrap4' is not a registered tag library. Must be one of:
admin_list
admin_modify
admin_urls
cache
i18n
l10n
log
static
tz
```

Comment: Hello, please provide the full traceback of your error in a text format

Answer (score 0):

Turned out I had the wrong virtual environment mapped in apache.